# How do I enable wifi debugging for Google Glass

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, google-glass

I am debugging my app with my head almost laying on my desk.  Neck cramps suck.

I am using Xamarin Mono in Visual Studio 2012 if that matters.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While "wireless" ADB interaction can be set up for Android phones, there does not appear to be a way to do this yet with Google Glass (corrections welcome for this assertion!).

You might consider one of the following manual debugging methods:

1. [hardware] Use a long usb cable connection to your development PC
2. Use ScreenCast and its ability to control Glass ([reference here)](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3068035?hl=en), excerpt follows

> Start a screencast and let others see what you see through Glass via
>   the display on your Android phone or tablet. You can even control
>   Glass from a screencast. Swipe on your screen like you would your
>   touchpad to use your phone as a remote control.